# psql utility file showing 0 bytes in greenplum db

Tags: psql, greenplum

we have greenplum instances running. Today, when I tried to login into DB, i found that psql is showing filesize as 0.

How can we recover from this? I have few other psql versions available in other postgres directory but not sure if plain copy paste will work?

What could be the reason for this? Only thing I tried is to run psql -d template1, followed by exit.

Comment: What "file" are you talking about? And what is the SQL statement you use to show that "file size"? **[Edit]** your question and add the query you are using - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Please try running `md5sum` on the offending "file" on some other hosts and see if it matches on those. At that point you could safely overwrite the corrupt file.  Maybe something like `runSomeScript > /path/to/file` happened inadvertently.